# Processing comma separated values using a loop in Unix

Tags: unix

I have a file which contains values like:

```
CA, PA, NY
ND, MO, MI
```

I need to process these values one by one. The flowchart will be as follows:

```
Enter loop -> Process CA; Process PA; Process NY -> Other commands -> Process ND; Process MO; Process MI -> End;
```

Is this possible using shell scripting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of two obvious ways.  If you'll have access to the `tr` utility (standard on any UNIX/Posix host) then you could `tr ',' '\n' < "$your_data_file" | while read each; do $process $each; done`  If not then you could probably still use the shell's IFS (inter-field separator) using something like: `cat  "$your_data_file"|  { IFS=','; while read line; do for each in $line; do echo $each; done; done; }`  (Note you can use `{}` grouping or `()` for a subshell ... they are effectively the same in this example).

Note you might have some extraneous whitespace in `$each` which you might want to filter out separately.